# Display consecutive snapshots in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, snapshot

I have a ip camera that is able to provide a rtsp stream or consecutive snapshots.
I'm trying to display this camera's live video on a webpage.

To display the rtsp stream I need to use a vlc plugin (I don't like this solution because I'm displaying the videos inside a leafletjs map. Leaflet does not handle vlc very well);

Is there some way to display the consecutive snapshots in a html canvas (or something else)?

Comment: So you've read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440265/rtsp-solution-for-javascript-html5 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5 right?

Comment: My cameras do not provide mjpeg stream and transcoding would work nice if I had only one camera (I need to handle around 100)

Comment: Some sort of RTSP to HTTP "conversion" layer is mandatory so you need VLC or some other client that does the transcoding (ffmpeg has ffserver that might work better for you). Regarding multiple cameras -> ffserver can handle that.

Comment: I know; For each camera I always have a Alix pc engine but I don't think it can handle the transcoding. That's why I looking for a solution that uses snapshots;

Comment: Maybe I can transcode the snapshots into a webm video?